# Why is BufferedReader read() picking up extra character

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am creating a Huffman Encode method that uses a buffered reader to read through a file, add new char values to an array entitled 'characters[128]' and if the char already exists in 'characters[128]' then 1 is added to the frequency/count of that char (which I store in charCount[128] at the same index as the char). I will attach my code, but when I run this, it prints out an unknown char () for the last char, meaning it is stopping the while loop one iteration later than it should. Do you know why, and how I can fix this?

```
public Playground() {
    char c;
    int size = 0;
    char[] characters = new char[128];
    int[] charCount = new int[128];
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {   
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        while ((c = (char)br.read()) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i) {
                if (size == 0) {
                    characters[i] = c;
                    charCount[i]++;
                    size++;
                    System.out.println("Letter/Count: " + characters[i] + "/" + charCount[i]);
                    break;
                }
                if (characters[i] == c) {
                    charCount[i]++;
                    break;
                } else if (i == size) {
                    characters[i] = c;
                    charCount[i]++;
                    size++;
                    System.out.println("Letter/Count:"+characters[i]+"/" + charCount[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION: " + e);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Main Is Working");
    Playground p = new Playground();
    System.out.println("Constructor is not");
}
```

Comment: Please add the full source code and the content of the file to your question so we can test whats going on. Keep in mind that charset plays a big game when using any readers in java.

Comment: Your code looks really bizarre.  I think we'd need to see the rest of the code to make any sense of it.  One thing that has me concerned is that `char` is always positive, I don't think it'll ever be equal to -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are converting int to char and then comparing it with again with an int -1. Do something like this :-

```
int i = -1;
while ((i = br.read()) != -1) {
     char c = (char)i;
     for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i) {
        if (size == 0) {
            characters[i] = c;
            charCount[i]++;
            size++;
            System.out.println("Letter/Count: " + characters[i] + "/" + charCount[i]);
            break;
        }

        if (characters[i] == c) {
            charCount[i]++;
            break;
        } else if (i == size) {
            characters[i] = c;
            charCount[i]++;
            size++;
            System.out.println("Letter/Count: " + characters[i] + "/" + charCount[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```